# Can't read the data I insert into SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My database doesn't update after the INSERT command I added to `DatabaseAccess` class.

I verified that in the function (`sign_user`) where I use the INSERT command, I can show the data I added on a toast message by using a query in the same function.
But when I try to receive the data I added from another function (`login_to_user`) by using a query, it doesn't return any data.

Here are my functions:

```
public boolean login_to_user(String user_name,String password){
    boolean login_status = false;
    Cursor user_info = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN+" WHERE user_name like '"+user_name+"' AND password like '"+password+"'",null);
    int row_count = user_info.getCount();
    user_info.close();
    if(row_count > 0){
        login_status = true;
    }
    return login_status;
}

public void sign_user(String user_name, String password, Context context){
        database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN+" (user_name,password) VALUES ('" + user_name + "','" + password + "')",null);
        Cursor user_info = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN+" WHERE user_name like '"+user_name+"' AND password like '"+password+"'",null);
        while(user_info.moveToNext()){
            String username=user_info.getString(0);
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,user_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

EDIT: my DatabaseAccess class:

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

public void sign_user(String user_name, String password, Context context){
    database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN+" (user_name,password) VALUES ('" + user_name + "','" + password + "')",null);
    Cursor user_info = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN+" WHERE user_name like '"+user_name+"' AND password like '"+password+"'",null);
    while(user_info.moveToNext()){
        String username=user_info.getString(0);
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,user_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

public boolean login_to_user(String user_name,String password){
    boolean login_status = false;
    Cursor user_info = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN+" WHERE user_name like '"+user_name+"' AND password like '"+password+"'",null);
    int row_count = user_info.getCount();
    user_info.close();
    if(row_count > 0){
        login_status = true;
    }
    return login_status;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code from the `DatabaseAccess` class and why don't you close the `user_info` in the `sign_user` method?

Comment: I added the DatabaseAccess class you asked. And about the closing the user_info, it's not important for now but i changed it.

Comment: When was your last test run? Did you update the DatabaseHelper class since then without updating the version number? Can you provide that class? Based doesn't on your code your not returning any rows (assuming the query is correct). Add a `Log.v("dataAccess", row_count)` immediately after you assign rite count so that you can see if any rows are returned

Comment: I finally find where i made mistake. When i try to use insert query, I use it with rawQuery function where i'm suppose to use execSql. i changed my insert query line with ``myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_LOGIN+" (user_name,password) VALUES ('"+user_name+"','"+password+"')");`` and now it works great. Thanks guys.